# Pen & Windows Ink, how does the handedness setting affect pen input?

Tags: windows, microsoft-surface, ink, pen

In Windows 10 Settings, there is a section for "Pen & Windows Ink".

One of these settings asks you to select the hand that you write with.

[image]

What exactly does this setting do? I searched online and [I found this source, which says](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-customize-active-pen-settings-windows-ink-windows-10-anniversary-update):

> **Choose which hand you write with:**
>
> Optimizes the pen experience for left-handed or right-handed use.

Unfortunately, I'm still not quite sure what this setting changes.

Does Windows interpet pen input differently depending on the handedness setting? I'm curious to know how Windows can use handedness to optimize pen input.

I am looking for answers that can explain *how* the handedness setting is used to improve handwriting recognition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This controls the direction that menus and other interface elements will come out of the various pen movements and gestures.

In right-handed mode the menus from a long press will display to the left of the pen tip, while in left-handed mode such elements will come from the right side so as not to appear under the user's hand.

There may be other ways this plays into the interface, but this is perhaps the main way handedness is used in the interface and the way most people will experience it.